# Could not resolve property - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have a problem with Hibernate. Im struggling with this since yesterday, it seems very easy but I have no idea why it is not working...

I have entity **Login.java**:

```
package offersmanager.model.entity;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Login {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String password;

    public Login(){
    }

    public Login(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Login(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.id = (Integer) jsonObject.get("id");
        this.username = (String) jsonObject.get("username");
        this.password = (String) jsonObject.get("password");
    }

    public JSONObject toJsonObject() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", this.id);
        jsonObject.put("username", this.username);
        jsonObject.put("password", this.password);
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And entity **TourOffice.java:**

```
package offersmanager.model.entity;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class TourOffice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String officeName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String eMail;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String phoneNumber;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String city;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String zipCode;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String address;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "login_id")
    Login login;

    public TourOffice(){
    }

    public TourOffice(String officeName, String eMail, String phoneNumber, String city, String zipCode, String address) {
        this.officeName = officeName;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public TourOffice(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.id = (Integer) jsonObject.get("id");
        this.officeName = (String) jsonObject.get("officeName");
        this.eMail = (String) jsonObject.get("eMail");
        this.phoneNumber = (String) jsonObject.get("phoneNumber");
        this.city = (String) jsonObject.get("city");
        this.zipCode = (String) jsonObject.get("zipCode");
        this.address = (String) jsonObject.get("address");
        this.login = (new Login((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("login")));
    }

    public JSONObject toJsonObject() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", this.id);
        jsonObject.put("officeName", this.officeName);
        jsonObject.put("eMail", this.eMail);
        jsonObject.put("phoneNumber", this.phoneNumber);
        jsonObject.put("city", this.city);
        jsonObject.put("zipCode", this.zipCode);
        jsonObject.put("address", this.address);
        jsonObject.put("login", this.login == null? null : login.toJsonObject());
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOfficeName() {
        return officeName;
    }

    public void setOfficeName(String officeName) {
        this.officeName = officeName;
    }

    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Login getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(Login login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

These entities are connected with @OneToOne relation.
What I'm trying to do is to find the name of my office (officeName) with field of Login class (username).

This is my function in **TourOfficeDAO.java:**

```
   public TourOffice findOfficeNameByLogin(String username) {
        Criteria name = createCriteria();
        name.add(Restrictions.eq("login.username", username));
        return (TourOffice) name.uniqueResult();
    }
```

It goes through TourOfficeService to my rest controller where this method is invoked. But it doesn't matter cause exeception is thrown in DAO:

> could not resolve property: login.username of:
>   offersmanager.model.entity.TourOffice; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   login.username of: offersmanager.model.entity.TourOffice

It can't find "login.username" and have no idea why... everything seems good.
I looked for similiar topics but I haven't still managed to make this works. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

This is my abstract class **DAO.java** where is the function createCriteria()

```
public abstract class DAO<MODEL> implements Serializable {

    public abstract Class<MODEL> getEntityClass();

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    protected Query createQuery(String query){
        return getSession().createQuery(query);
    }

    protected SQLQuery createSQLQuery(String query){
        return getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    }

    protected Criteria createCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MODEL findById(Integer id) {
        return (MODEL) getSession().get(getEntityClass(), id);
    }

    public void save(MODEL entity) {
        getSession().save(entity);
        getSession().flush();
    }

    public void update(MODEL entity) {
        getSession().update(entity);
        getSession().flush();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(MODEL entity) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        getSession().flush();
    }

    public void delete(MODEL entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
        getSession().flush();
    }

    public List<MODEL> list(){
        Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<MODEL> list = criteria.list();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove boilerplate getters/setters code from the question and provide the code of createCriteria()

Comment: What do you bean by "boilerplate getters/setters"? I added createCriteria() code.

Comment: It means they are irrelevant for your question, so you should remove them.

Comment: I have pasted them cause in some topic someone said that getters and setter have influence on Hibernate Queries

Comment: Offtopic question: Why are your properties not private?

Comment: Yeah, they sould be :) I'll have to change it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first to create an alias like that:

```
  public TourOffice findOfficeNameByLogin(String username) {
    Criteria name = createCriteria();
    name.createAlias("login", "login");
    name.add(Restrictions.eq("login.username", username));
    return (TourOffice) name.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now it works. Thank you. But I don't know why i had to create alias. My friend has very similiar code, but with relation OneToMany (or ManyToMany - dont remember exactly) and he didnt have to create alias.

Comment: When you create an alias Hibernate make a "join" request (you can show sql if you want to see SQL generated by Hibernate). In the case of your friend join information may be set on OneToMany or ManyToMany attribute (check @JoinTable information)